# [RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: SmartContract using web3j

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j, java

I am following this tutorial for deployment of contract https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ibAh04Csp0M&index=33&list=PL16WqdAj66SCOdL6XIFbke-XQg2GW_Avg

but i am getting

```
[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: smartcontract.Counter.<init>(java.lang.String, org.web3j.protocol.Web3j, org.web3j.crypto.Credentials, org.web3j.tx.gas.ContractGasProvider)]
```

on line

```
val deploy=Counter.deploy(web3j, credentials, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT).send()
```

here is my code

```
def getCredentials() :Credentials ={
    val private_key= "my main account address"
    val credentials= Credentials.create(private_key);
    credentials
  }

def deployContract(web3j: Web3j,credentials:Credentials/*transactionManager: TransactionManager*/):String ={
    val GAS_LIMIT = BigInteger.valueOf(6721975L);
    val GAS_PRICE = BigInteger.valueOf(20000000000L);
    val deploy = Counter.deploy(web3j, credentials, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT).send().getContractAddress
    deploy
    }

def counterContractDemo() = Action {
    val web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("http://localhost:8080/"))
    val deployAddress = deployContract(web3j,getCredentials)
    Ok(deployAddress)
  }
```

here is the piece of contract wrapped java code

```
Counter.java
public static RemoteCall<Counter> deploy(Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return deployRemoteCall(Counter.class, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, "");
    }

    public static RemoteCall<Counter> deploy(Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return deployRemoteCall(Counter.class, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, "");
    }

    public static Counter load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return new Counter(contractAddress, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    public static Counter load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return new Counter(contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }
```

i am running ethereum on privatenet please help what i am missing

Comment: have you included 
    <script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

Comment: where should i add this ?